# Looking to distinguish between a $query response with data in it and a $query response without data in it

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.4

I am having trouble trying to distinguish when I have a response with data in it and when a response does not. I am using Laravel 5.4 with a model and controller that are connected. I have this code as for my model:

```
public function scopeCheckForPrevious($verify)

{
  json_encode($query = \App\Address::where('address', 'like', '%'.$verify.'%')

  ->get());

  return $query;



}
```

and this as my controller code:

```
public function show()
    {
      $result = new Address;
      $check = $_POST['address'];

      $address = $result->scopeCheckForPrevious($check);

      print_r($address);

    }
```

When I print my results I have this when I have a $query that returns data:

Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => App\Address Object ( [fillable:protected] => Array ( [0] => address [1] => city [2] => state ) [connection:protected] => mysql [table:protected] => [primaryKey:protected] => id [keyType:protected] => int [incrementing] => 1 [with:protected] => Array ( ) [perPage:protected] => 15 [exists] => 1 [wasRecentlyCreated] => [attributes:protected] => Array ( [id] => 1 [address] => 1024 s main st [city] => corona [state] => ca [created_at] => 2017-05-15 01:45:28 [updated_at] => 2017-05-15 01:45:28 ) [original:protected] => Array ( [id] => 1 [address] => 1024 s main st [city] => corona [state] => ca [created_at] => 2017-05-15 01:45:28 [updated_at] => 2017-05-15 01:45:28 ) [casts:protected] => Array ( ) [dates:protected] => Array ( ) [dateFormat:protected] => [appends:protected] => Array ( ) [events:protected] => Array ( ) [observables:protected] => Array ( ) [relations:protected] => Array ( ) [touches:protected] => Array ( ) [timestamps] => 1 [hidden:protected] => Array ( ) [visible:protected] => Array ( ) [guarded:protected] => Array ( [0] => * ) ) [1] => App\Address Object ( [fillable:protected] => Array ( [0] => address [1] => city [2] => state ) [connection:protected] => mysql [table:protected] => [primaryKey:protected] => id [keyType:protected] => int [incrementing] => 1 [with:protected] => Array ( ) [perPage:protected] => 15 [exists] => 1 [wasRecentlyCreated] => [attributes:protected] => Array ( [id] => 4 [address] => 1024 s main st. [city] => corona [state] => ca [created_at] => 2017-05-15 01:47:39 [updated_at] => 2017-05-15 01:47:39 ) [original:protected] => Array ( [id] => 4 [address] => 1024 s main st. [city] => corona [state] => ca [created_at] => 2017-05-15 01:47:39 [updated_at] => 2017-05-15 01:47:39 ) [casts:protected] => Array ( ) [dates:protected] => Array ( ) [dateFormat:protected] => [appends:protected] => Array ( ) [events:protected] => Array ( ) [observables:protected] => Array ( ) [relations:protected] => Array ( ) [touches:protected] => Array ( ) [timestamps] => 1 [hidden:protected] => Array ( ) [visible:protected] => Array ( ) [guarded:protected] => Array ( [0] => * ) ) ) )

And I have this when I return a query with no response:

Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( ) )

I want to make an if else statement and have tried to just check if $address is NULL or not like this:

```
public function show()
{
  $result = new Address;
  $check = $_POST['address'];

  $address = $result->scopeCheckForPrevious($check);



  if($address == NULL)
 {
    print_r($address);
  }

  else
  {
    echo "You have no responses";
  }
```

But it keeps responding only with the else echo.

Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `count()`:

```
if( count($address) == 0)
{
    echo "You have no responses";
}

else
{
    print_r($address);
}
```